# Grouping by preference + considered options

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Consider the following dataframe:

```
> A
  primero segundo Pref comentario
1       A       B    B   bavodkzn
2       B       A    B   tgczxobh
3       B       C    B   wavkflpr
4       C       A    C   ujplgzkh
5       A       C    C   hfsnrdaq
6       A       B    A       asdf
```

Each row contains the following: `primero` and `segundo`, which are the products tested by an individual; `Pref` which is the prefered option by said individual and `comentario` which holds a comment made by the individual.
For my analysis, I care only for the prefered product and the two products they have tested (**not** the order). Thus, the expected output would be:

```
> Group_1
  primero segundo Pref comentario
1       A       B    B   bavodkzn
2       B       A    B   tgczxobh
> Group 2
  primero segundo Pref comentario
3       B       C    B   wavkflpr
> Group 3
  primero segundo Pref comentario
4       C       A    C   ujplgzkh
5       A       C    C   hfsnrdaq
> Group 4
 primero segundo Pref comentario
6       A       B    A       asdf
```

This can be done through loops but I would assume there to exist more straightforward solutions, maybe through `dplyr`.

`dput` of the data:

```
structure(list(primero = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A"), segundo = c("B", 
"A", "C", "A", "C", "B"), Pref = c("B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A"
), comentario = c("bavodkzn", "tgczxobh", "wavkflpr", "ujplgzkh", 
"hfsnrdaq", "asdf")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**EDIT**

Looking at the response, I see I have not made it clear enough what the expected output is:

- Data should be split regarding `primero`, `segundo` **and** `Pref`.
- A given group *i* should contain individuals that have chosen the same product as prefered (e.g. `Pref==B`) from the same choices (`primero` and `segundo`), no matter the order of these last two.

Thus,

```
  primero segundo Pref comentario
1       A       B    B   bavodkzn
2       B       A    B   tgczxobh
```

Should all belong to the same group while

```
  primero segundo Pref comentario
6       A       B    A       asdf
```

Does not belong to the same group, as their preference is different. I have updated the dataset and the expected result.

Comment: It's unclear what you intend to do. You show expected output but give no clear logic as to how this output is to be obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `primero` and `segundo` into vector, then sort it (to make A-B and B-A equivalent) and concatanate. Then just split on this variable + Pref variable:

```
library(tidyverse)

A %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(x = map2_chr(primero, segundo, ~c(.x, .y) %>% sort() %>% str_c(collapse = ', '))) %>%
  split(list(.$x, .$Pref)) %>%
  map(~select(.x, -x)) %>%
  `[`(map_lgl(., ~nrow(.x) > 0))
```

Output:

```
$`A, B.A`
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  primero segundo Pref  comentario
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>     
1 A       B       A     asdf      

$`A, B.B`
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  primero segundo Pref  comentario
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>     
1 A       B       B     bavodkzn  
2 B       A       B     tgczxobh  

$`B, C.B`
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  primero segundo Pref  comentario
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>     
1 B       C       B     wavkflpr  

$`A, C.C`
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  primero segundo Pref  comentario
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>     
1 C       A       C     ujplgzkh  
2 A       C       C     hfsnrdaq
```

Comment: sorry I had not made it clear enough what I expected, please see the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

From your expected output, it seems you need to catch duplicates from the first 2 columns (`primero` and `segundo`). In that case, you can sort the entries rowwise and use `duplicated` to create the groups, i.e.

```
cumsum(!duplicated(apply(A[c(1,2)], 1, function(i) toString(sort(i)))))
#[1] 1 1 2 3 3
```

To apply and split (if needed) the original data frame,

```
v1 <- cumsum(!duplicated(apply(A[c(1,2)], 1, function(i) toString(sort(i)))))
split(A, v1)
```

which gives,

> ```
> $`1`
>   primero segundo Pref comentario
> 1       A       B    B   bavodkzn
> 2       B       A    B   tgczxobh
>
> $`2`
>   primero segundo Pref comentario
> 3       B       C    B   wavkflpr
>
> $`3`
>   primero segundo Pref comentario
> 4       C       A    C   ujplgzkh
> 5       A       C    C   hfsnrdaq
> ```

Comment: sorry I had not made it clear enough what I expected, please see the edited question.